# Laravel 5.1 Mass Assignment Fillable Properties Being Ignored on Update?

Tags: laravel-5.1, mass-assignment

I have the following models:

```
class User {

    public function recruiter()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Recruiter');
     }

 }

 class Recruiter extends Model {

   public function jobs()
   {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Job');
    }

 }

 class Job extends Model {

    protected $fillable = [
      'job_type_id',
      'recruiter_id',
      'start_at',
      'end_at',
      'job_title',
      'job_ref',
      'job_desc'

    ];

     // other stuff
 }
```

When I call the following create method the fillable properties on the Job model work as expected.

```
$job = Auth::user()->recruiter->jobs()->create($request->all());
```

When I call the update method the fillable properties are ignored and end up with mass assignment vulnerability.

```
Auth::user()->recruiter->jobs()->update($request->all());
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Have you tried to `var_dump()` the `$request->all()`? If yes, what does it return?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you need to pass the `id` of the job as well (Laravel dosen't know what to update). So added to the `fillable` array.

```
class Job extends Model {

    protected $fillable = [
      'id',
      'job_type_id',
      'recruiter_id',
      'start_at',
      'end_at',
      'job_title',
      'job_ref',
      'job_desc'

    ];

     // other stuff
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is a weird bug. With this, still in Laravel 5.7.

You need to do this, for it to respect $fillable:

```
$jobs = Auth::user()->recruiter->jobs();
$jobs->update($request->all());
```

Don't ask me why, but if you try:

```
(Auth::user()->recruiter->jobs())->update($request->all());
```

It just ignores $fillable.